# How can I change the policy of a websocket?

Tags: java, websocket, jetty

I use a program (I didn't developped by myself. I downloaded it from Internet) to link two hosts and exchange some data. When I run the program I get this:

```
    WebSocketSession[websocket=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[ros.BigMessageRosBridge@1e7c87b],behavior=CLIENT,connection=WebSocketClientConnection@645cd7{IDLE}{f=Flusher[queueSize=0,aggregateSize=0,failure=null],g=Generator[CLIENT,validating],p=Parser@197774[ExtensionStack,s=START,c=0,len=0,f=null,p=WebSocketPolicy@1c898e2[behavior=CLIENT,maxTextMessageSize=2560000,maxTextMessageBufferSize=5120000,maxBinaryMessageSize=65536,maxBinaryMessageBufferSize=32768,asyncWriteTimeout=60000,idleTimeout=300000,inputBufferSize=4096]]},remote=WebSocketRemoteEndpoint@11bd6a3[batching=true],incoming=JettyAnnotatedEventDriver[ros.BigMessageRosBridge@1e7c87b],outgoing=ExtensionStack[queueSize=0,extensions=[],incoming=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession,outgoing=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.WebSocketClientConnection]]
```

However, the messages I'm exchanging exceed the values defined in the websocket policy described above. I would like to know how can I change the websocket policy specially those related to inputBufferSize and maxTextMessageBufferSize. This is my fisrt time I work with websocket. I'm really lost.
Any help or suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have access to sources or what configuration options are available to you? Unless they specifically provided avenues to configure it at runtime, this isn't something you can configure via system properties or env variables

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean exactly. But, the websocket is created using @websocket annotation. Then, I create WebSocketClient to connect to the host, read data, and transmit it.

Comment: OK that answers the sources, you have them. Look at http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/jetty-websocket-server-api.html for examples configuring jetty

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem.